Cloudflare doesn't accept multiple bytes range
I have a large file deployed to R2, and want some portions of it.
Accordingly to MDN, the Range header can specify multiple ranges in the form of Range: bytes=0-10, 20,50. Anyway, when I try to make an HTTP request to the endpoint, it returns an error.
I have tried with a single range, and it returns the correct response
curl -H 'Range: bytes=0-10' 'https://xxx.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/yyyy&x-id=GetObject'

Instead the following request returns an error:
curl -H 'Range: bytes=0-10, 20-50' 'https://xxx.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/yyyy&x-id=GetObject'

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Invalid Argument: range must be in format &apos;bytes=start-end&apos;, &apos;bytes=start-&apos; or &apos;bytes=-suffix&apos;.&apos;</Message></Error>

Is the feature not fully implemented in Cloudflare R2 or I understood wrongly somewhere?

I'm not an expert in Cloudflare R2, but it seems that many servers will ignore range headers with multiple ranges. See paragraph after highlight Also, Cloudflare's proxy doesn't seem to have great range support either.

Cloudflare R2 implements the AWS S3 API, and as per the AWS S3 object documentation: Amazon S3 doesn't support retrieving multiple ranges of data per GET request.
